# Deep merge Ruby hashes with no new keys

Tags: ruby

How can I deep merge two Ruby hash so that the second hash only override the first hash without adding any key to it?

Example:

Merge

```
{
  "dog" => {
    "ear" => "big",
    "hair" => "smooth"
  }
}
```

with

```
{
  "dog" => {
    "ear" => "small",
    "tail" => "curve"
  }
}
```

will have result

```
{
  "dog" => {
    "ear" => "small", # Only override key "ear"
    "hair" => "smooth"
    # Without adding key "tail"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this? Please show your attempt.

Comment: @MarkThomas I added my own answer. Please see and suggest some improvement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I answer my own question with two versions:

1. Procedural style

   ```
   def exclusive_deep_merge(merge_to, merge_from)
     merged = merge_to.clone
     merge_from.each do |key, value|
       # Only override existing key
       if merged.keys.include?(key)
         # Deep merge for nested hash
         if value.is_a?(Hash) && merged[key].is_a?(Hash)
           merged[key] = exclusive_deep_merge(merged[key], value)
         else
           merged[key] = value
         end
       end
     end
     merged
   end
   ```
2. The monkey-patching

   ```
   class Hash
     def exclusive_deep_merge(other_hash)
       dup.exclusive_deep_merge!(other_hash)
     end

     def exclusive_deep_merge!(other_hash)
       other_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
         if self.keys.include? k
           self[k] = self[k].is_a?(Hash) && v.is_a?(Hash) ? self[k].exclusive_deep_merge(v) : v
         end
       end
       self
     end
   end
   ```

Any comments on improvement are warmly welcome ♥

Comment: P/S: Is the name "exclusive_deep_merge" suitable?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like something I would ask in an interview. I hope you're not cheating ;-)

```
def my_merge(h1, h2)
  h1.inject({}) do |h, (k, v)|
    if Hash === v
      h[k] = my_merge(v, h2[k] || {})
    else
      h[k] = h2[k] || h1[k]
    end
    h
  end
end
```

And a test :-)

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe 'my_merge' do

  it "maintains same keys" do
    h1 = {
      "dog" => {
        "ear" => "big",
        "hair" => "smooth"
      }
    }

    h2 = {
      "dog" => {
        "ear" => "small",
        "tail" => "curve"
      }
    }

    expected = {
      "dog" => {
        "ear" => "small", # Only override key "ear"
        "hair" => "smooth"
        # Without adding key "tail"
      }
    }
    my_merge(h1, h2).must_equal(expected)
  end
end
```

Comment: Tim, just a couple of small points: 1. if you (are using >= Ruby 1.9 and) replace the first line with `h1.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|` you can delete that pesky `h` at the end of the block.  (Note the change to the order of the block arguments.). 2. the Ruby Style Guide favors `is_a? Hash` over `Hash === v` (but it doesn't bother me).

Answer (score 0):

Recursively (and similar to @Tim's answer, which I hadn't seen when I started),

```
def merge_em(h1, h2)
  h1.each_key do |k|
    if h2.key?(k)
      if h1[k].is_a? Hash
        merge_em(h1[k], h2[k]) 
      else
        h1[k] = h2[k]
      end
    end
  end   
end           

h = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h1))

merge_em(h, h2)
```

I've used `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h1))` to make a deep copy of `h1`.  If it's OK to change `h1`, just

```
merge_em(h1, h2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is easy-understanding enough.

To know if a hash includes some key, you can just use `has_key?`, `key?` or `include?` methods.

Here is my code.

```
Hash.send :define_method, :exclusive_merge do |other|
  other.each do |k, v|
    if self.has_key?(k)
      if self[k].is_a?(Hash) and v.is_a?(Hash)
        self[k].exclusive_merge v
      else
        self[k] = v
      end
    end
  end
  self
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the example here to deep merge hash with an other value, even it is not a hash.

```rb
class Hash
   def deep_merge other
      return self if other.nil? or other == {}
      
      other_hash = other.is_a?(Hash) && other || { nil => other }
      common_keys = self.keys & other_hash.keys
      base_hash = (other_hash.keys - common_keys).reduce({}) do |res, key|
         res[key] = other_hash[key]
         res
      end
      
      self.reduce(base_hash) do |res, (key, value)|
         new =
         if common_keys.include?(key)
            case value
            when Hash
               value.deep_merge(other_hash[key])
            when Array
               value.concat([ other_hash[key] ].compact.flatten(1))
            when NilClass
               other_hash[key]
            else
               [ value, other_hash[key] ].compact.flatten(1)
            end
         else
            value
         end
         
         res[key] = new
         res
      end
   end
end
```

It allows to correctly merge embedded values, when they are of incompatible types, like hash and array, array and non-array, etc.